# React Router with Eletron: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron, jsx

I was trying to use React Router with Electron to navigate to another page when click and add a slide transition animation, but it giving this error:

> act.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `m`.

I suppose the error might be in here:

Home.js

```
import { HashRouter, Route, Routes, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Search from './Search';

<HashRouter>
  <div>
    <div>
      <Link to="/search"><h2>test</h2></Link>
    </div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/search' component={Search} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</HashRouter>
```

or

Seach.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Search.css";
import { Weather } from "./weather";

const Search = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search;
```

Here the entire code: https://github.com/vitorhugo1207/Weatherco

If I left say something important please tell me.

Comment: I don't see any issue with *this* specific code. It's possible the problem is downstream. Try commenting out nearly all of the JSX in the `Home` and incrementally uncomment/build/test one element at-a-time until you find where it breaks, then repeat the process in *that* element/component until you find the problematic code.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your comment, clue and correction. I did almost what you said and I can reach the resolve for me, thanks!

Comment: I see, so you had installed `react-router-dom@6` but thought you were still using v5. Glad to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolve for me was `switch` to `Routes` and `component` to `element`, but it was creating a new problem: React was just adding the elements from `Search` intend navigate to `Search`, then I change the struct of my program:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home.js';
import Search from './Search.js';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="search" element={<Search />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import {Weather} from './weather';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  //Some Codes...

  return (
    <div className='main'>
        <div className='head'>
            <Link to={"/search"}>Search</Link>
            <br/>
            <Link to={"/"}>Home</Link>

            {/*Some Codes...*/}
        </div>
        {/*Some Codes...*/}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Then I include the hole `App.js` inside a `<HashRouter>` after I set `<Routes>` in `App` and call a `<Link>` when I want to set a link.

If you wanna see the entire code: https://github.com/vitorhugo1207/Weatherco/tree/f4fde838a58ac6fa34902cb198691dcdab318555

This as simple problem to resolve, maybe my lack of attention turn it more hard, but I hope this can help some people who have the similar problem.

Packages:

- copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0
- craco@0.0.3
- electron-packager@17.1.1
- electron@25.3.1
- react-dom@18.2.0
- react-router-dom@6.14.2
- react-scripts@5.0.1
- react@18.2.0
- webpack-dev-middleware@6.1.1
- webpack-node-externals@3.0.0